# SyntaxError on setup.py

Tags: python, py2exe

I am new to python and I am trying to make an exe file, using py2exe, from a python code I made. I made the following setup.py file following a tutorial on how to use py2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from glob import glob
import py2exe

setup(console=['App.py'])

data_files = [("msvcr90.dll", glob(r'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcr90.dll\*.*'))]
setup(data_files=data_files, etc)

sys.path.append("C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcr90.dll")
```

When I try to run it in cmd I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

I have read several other posts on this error basically saying that I should have the "etc" before "data_files". However when I do this, I get a name error `undefined name sys`.

I want to include `msvcr90.dll` file with the setup.py

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `import sys` at the beginning, and the etc before data_files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read several other posts on this error basically saying that I should **have the "etc" before "data_files"**. However when I do this, I get a name error `undefined name sys`

That IS the solution to this problem, though you will then encounter the same error with `etc` as it is not defined anywhere (I believe it is meant to be an example to show that `setup` can accept other arguments, and not meant to be used literally in your code).

You are getting `undefined name sys` because that is another, unrelated issue in your code.

You should add `import sys`.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from glob import glob
import py2exe
import sys

setup(console=['App.py'])

data_files = [("msvcr90.dll", glob(r'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcr90.dll\*.*'))]
setup(data_files=data_files)

sys.path.append("C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcr90.dll")
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that worked, but now I have `undefined name etc`. Honestly I am not sure why etc is needed, It's just how it is on the tutorial

Comment: @MarcoNunez I believe it is meant to be an example to show that `setup` can accept other arguments, and not meant to be used literally in your code.